# can I use THIS pointer in friend class?

Tags: c++, pointers, include

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Street;

class CrossStreet

{

        private:

             char m_chName;
             Street* m_acLoS;
             int m_nNoS;
             static int m_nCSid;
        public:
             CrossStreet()
             {
                  Init();
                  m_chName = m_nCSid;
             }
             CrossStreet(char chName)
             {
                  Init();
                  m_chName = chName;
             }

             /** Problem is here **/
             void AddStreet(Street* const cStreet)
             {
                  m_acLoS[++m_nNoS] = cStreet;
             }

             ~CrossStreet()
             {
                  delete[] m_acList;
             }

             void Init()
             {
                  m_nNoS = 0;
                  m_acLoS = 0;
                  m_nCSid++;
             }

             friend class Street;
};

class Street

{

         private:

              int m_nDistance;

         public:

              Street(CrossStreet& cHead, CrossStreet& cTail, int nDistance)
              {
                   CreateStreet(cHead,cTail,nDistance);
              }

              void CreateStreet(CrossStreet& cHead, CrossStreet& cTail, int nDistance)
              {
                   m_nDistance = nDistance;
                   cHead.AddStreet(Street* const THIS);
                   cTail.AddStreet(Street* const THIS);

              }

};
```

when I compile above code, this throw error:

```
-->>invalid use of incomplete 'struct Street'
-->>forward declaration of 'struct Street'
```

function AddStreet of an object of 'CrossStreet' was called at an object of 'Street', to add 'THIS street object to member variable of CrossStreet object. So I think I can use THIS pointer in this case but it not compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such things as a `THIS` pointer. There is a `this` pointer though. So your code in `CreateStreet` is invalid (and not only for that). The correct syntax would be:

```
cHead.AddStreet(this); // no cast needed
```

The problem in `AddStreet` is that you have defined `m_acLoS` as a pointer-to-Street. So `m_acLoS[x]` is of type `Street`, and not `Street*`. But you can't use a `Street` object there since you don't have a complete definition of `Street` at that point. You can only use pointers to Street in `CrossStreet`. (Additionally, you're lacking storage allocation for `m_acLoS`, so even if you could use that type there, and if the assignment was legal, it would still be a bug).

Depending on what you're after, a `std::vector<Street*>` or `std::list<Street*>` or some other container could be what you're looking for, instead of that incorrect member array. (But beware that you're responsible for managing the lifetime of those pointers.)

Comment: thanks you so much. Your post is really clue. But may be really have the THIS pointer which i have used after visit this link:

Answer (score 3):

Has nothing to do with the `this` pointer, it has to do with the forward declaration.  You are saying that `Street` is a `class` in your forward declaration, but it doesn't specify it's definition so attempting to use it's definition before it is defined is an error.

That is, with a forward declaration:

```
class Street;
```

You can say things like:

```
Street* pS
Street& rS
```

Because those do not require the definition of Street.  But once you make use of it in a way that does require the definition (assigning the Street object) you do require the full definition.

// m_acLoS is a Street*, so m_acLoS[...] refers to a Street.
   m_acLoS[++m_nNoS] = cStreet;

It looks like you really want the array to be an array of pointer to Street instead of array to Street (and in fact a vector would probably be better).

But, in general, since you have CrossStreet depending on Street and Street depending on CrossStreet, you should put the declarations for each class in their own header files, and the implementations in their own .cpp files, in that way the .cpp files with the source can #include both complete declarations before any code that uses them.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of people have already told you about the problem. This focuses more on a solution. The one I generally favor is separating the class implementation from the class definition. I'd re-structure the code something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Street;

class CrossStreet {
    char m_chName;
    Street* m_acLoS;
    int m_nNoS;
    static int m_nCSid;
    void Init();
public:
    CrossStreet();
    CrossStreet(char chName);
    void AddStreet(Street* const cStreet);
    ~CrossStreet();
    friend class Street;
};

class Street {
    int m_nDistance;
public:
    Street(CrossStreet& cHead, CrossStreet& cTail, int nDistance);
    void CreateStreet(CrossStreet& cHead, CrossStreet& cTail, int nDistance);
};


CrossStreet::CrossStreet() {
    Init();
    m_chName = m_nCSid;
}

CrossStreet::CrossStreet(char chName) {
    Init();
    m_chName = chName;
}

void CrossStreet::AddStreet(Street* const cStreet) {
    m_acLoS[++m_nNoS] = cStreet;
}

CrossStreet::~CrossStreet() {
    delete[] m_acList;
}

CrossStreet::void Init() {
    m_nNoS = 0;
    m_acLoS = 0;
    m_nCSid++;
}

Street::Street(CrossStreet& cHead, CrossStreet& cTail, int nDistance) {
    CreateStreet(cHead,cTail,nDistance);
}

void Street::CreateStreet(CrossStreet& cHead, CrossStreet& cTail, int nDistance) {
    m_nDistance = nDistance;
    cHead.AddStreet(this);
    cTail.AddStreet(this);
}
```

So, the basic idea here is a class declaration, then the class definitions, then the implementations of the member functions. Also note that I've made `CrossStreet::Init` private, since it apparently should only ever be used by members of `CrossStreet`.

As a final note, please, for God's sake, pick out some decent names for your variables. The only name you've used that's even halfway meaningful and readable is `m_nDistance`. Things like `m_chName` and `m_acLos` are really and truly awful. These look a lot like names I've invented when writing diatribes about the evils of Hungarian Notation and the ugly, unreadable mess you can get from it.